# What is apiKey.properties?

Tags: stormpath

I am testing Spring Boot WebMVC with Stormpath and I do not understand the concept behind the key pair of `apiKey.properties` and why I have to download it to some local developer computer.

Why do I have to make a system environment variable? Do I have to make the same env variable when I deploy my .jar on another server? Can I place it in another directory and not in my home directory? How?

Could anyone elaborate a bit about the meaning of this `apiKey.properties` file?

Answer (score 1):

The `apiKey.properties` file contains your Stormpath API Key and Secret. The file itself isn't actually needed for your WebMVC project, but the API credentials (key and secret) are. Without the credentials, your project won't be able to communicate with Stormpath.

According to [the docs](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/config.html#api-key), the API credentials can be stored in a number of places:

- `$HOME/.stormpath/apiKey.properties`
- Environment variables (`STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID` and `STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET`)
- Any [Spring Boot external configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) location. However, for security reasons, it's not recommended to store your API credentials elsewhere.

Any machine that is hosting your project will need the API credentials configured by one of these methods.